# Inserting trouble

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, sql-insert

I have two tables on my database "tipical_bd".
One table "**linha**" where the name has a primary key "**endereco_ip**" and another table named postos with foreign key "**endereco_ip**" and variable "**posto_ID**".

In my database I can not put the value from "**endereco_ip**" in the table "**posto_ID**".
The primary key "**endereco_ip**" gets correctly the value but I can not put this value in the table "**posto_ID**" for later reference by doing a search , someone can tell me what is wrong in the code ?

```vb
Private Sub inserir_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles inserir.Click
    Dim insertip_bd As String = "INSERT INTO linha (endereco_ip) VALUES (@endereco_ip)"
    Dim inserirposto_bd As String = "INSERT INTO posto (postos_id, endereco_ip) VALUES(@posto_id, (SELECT linha.endereco_ip FROM linha WHERE linha.endereco_ip=posto.endereco_ip))"

    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(myConnectionString)

    Dim command_ip As New MySqlCommand(insertip_bd, connection)
    Dim command_posto As New MySqlCommand(inserirposto_bd, connection)


    If (ipText.Text = "" Or postoText.Text = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Não foi inserido nenhum valor")
    Else
        ip_address = CInt(ipText.Text)
        posto = CInt(postoText.Text)

        Try
            connection.Open()
            'ListBox1.Items.Add(". . .")
            command_ip.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco_ip", ip_address)
            command_posto.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postos_id", connection)

            command_ip.ExecuteNonQuery()
            command_posto.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Erro de ligação", "AVISO!!!")
        End Try

        connection.Close()
        command_ip = Nothing
        command_posto = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Question: why are you doing: '"INSERT INTO posto (postos_id, endereco_ip) VALUES(@posto_id, (SELECT linha.endereco_ip FROM linha WHERE linha.endereco_ip=posto.endereco_ip)'    instead of just doing: "INSERT INTO posto (postos_id, endereco_ip) VALUES(@posto_id, @endereco_ip)"

Comment: Because endereco_ip its a primary key, and I pretend maked a reference for searching. ALready try putting the way you mentioned but the value endere_ip not appears in the postos table .
The idea is write the endereco_ip automatically assume in Table Postos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current insert:-

```
INSERT INTO posto (postos_id, endereco_ip) 
VALUES(@posto_id, (SELECT linha.endereco_ip FROM linha WHERE linha.endereco_ip=posto.endereco_ip))
```

I would normally write as:-

```
INSERT INTO posto (postos_id, endereco_ip) 
SELECT @posto_id, linha.endereco_ip 
FROM linha 
WHERE linha.endereco_ip=posto.endereco_ip
```

Doing this seems more logical to me, and makes what seems to be an attempt at a join more obvious.

Your WHERE clause is checking *linha.endereco_ip=posto.endereco_ip* but you are not select / joining against the posto table so there is no value of posto.endereco.

As it is now I can't work out where you want to get this value from to check, unless you want to check the fixed value and use the id from the table (something like this):-

```
INSERT INTO posto (postos_id, linha_id) 
SELECT @posto_id, linha.endereco_ip 
FROM linha 
WHERE linha.endereco_ip=@endereco_ip
```